# C# command line mode return a 64 bit number

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, 64-bit

The Enviornment.Exit() method can return 32 bit numbers.
Is it possible to return a 64 bit number in command line execution mode

I am returning a computed value using Enviornment.Exit() and not an error code, for another batch file to read directly.

Is there any way to directly exit a 64 bit value , other than using temporary storage like registry/file?

Comment: Why would anyone need this? `Int32` has enough range to keep all [system error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms681381.aspx) possible. Be aware, there is an implicit conversation from `Int32` to `Int64`.

Comment: If it's for IPC you may want to use a different method instead of process return code. If it's for error...wow...do you map so many different errors?!?!?

Comment: I'm assuming you're targeting Windows?

Comment: Currently, in windows target only.  I use Enviornment.Exit to return a computed value (not an error code) for another application to read it directly.

Comment: @Nalanchiracoder that's not good practice, I recommend using a different strategy to let two applications communicate. The exitcode is there to give a clear indication to let other systems/apps know if there was an error. As MSDN says "Use a non-zero number to indicate an error."

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses 32-bit signed integers as exit codes, so unfortunately you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the number in the current dot net framework is defined as an integer. Ref: "ExitCode" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Furthermore, it's a basic rule in Windows applications to return a 32-bit integer as exit code. A standard thus. You wouldn't want to deviate on that.

Also note their remark on [that MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The ExitCode property is a signed 32-bit integer. To prevent the property from returning a negative exit code, you should not use values greater than or equal to 0x80000000.

Also, could you tell us why you'd want to return a 64bit number? Isn't there another way of translating the "exitcode"?

Comment: I am returning a computed value using Enviornment.Exit() and not an error code, for another application to read directly.

Comment: that's not good practice, I recommend using a different strategy to let two applications communicate. The exitcode is there to give a clear indication to let other systems/apps know if there was an error. As MSDN says "Use a non-zero number to indicate an error."

In other words, it's not the tool for the job, you should think of a different strategy to communicate output. ExitCode is there to indicate either success or an error.

Comment: I don't know the scenario of your application. If you could describe that in more detail then we'd be able to offer more help. But generally speaking there are different options. Either output to a file, or output to console and then exit with 0 (or else if application really failed). You could add startup parameters to your application so that it can choose a strategy that suits. Such as "-outputToConsole" or "-OutputToFile <fileName>" etc..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarifications.
I modified the command line execution to update a file with the o/p value that can be read by other application